# How to scroll the screen in an android app?

Tags: android

I designed this GUI in android for my app (web_guide)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMCW.jpg

and I want to scroll the screen to add new image buttons so that the user scroll the screen to find new items

I tried to use "scroll view" but I do not know how to use it

please anybody help me

here is my current xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Web_guide"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/google_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtube"
    android:background="@drawable/youtube"
    android:layout_below="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/instagram"
    android:background="@drawable/insta"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/instagram"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/iii" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_logo_bluebg_2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/linkedin_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google_plus"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:background="@drawable/google_plus_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/pinterest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pinterest_alt" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/flicker"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linked_in"
    android:background="@drawable/flicker" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/vine"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/vine" />
```

Comment: `I tried to use "scroll view" but I not know how to use it` - could you post what you tried? Because that is an option. There are a few others but they are a little more complex to implement and if you can't figure out a ScrollView those are going to be a headache for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Web_guide"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtube"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:layout_below="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/instagram"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/instagram"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google_plus"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/pinterest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/flicker"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linked_in"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/vine"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Output for this is 
 
[image: Output image]

Comment: I also  tried your advise but I got this strange layout (http://imgur.com/hzvV0Ec) and the screen do not scroll when I run the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your buttons into a LinearLayout (which I assume that you're doing already). Then put that LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. The layout parameters for the layouts should be:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" ... >
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" ... >
Button 1
Button 2...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried your advise but I got this strange layout (http://imgur.com/hzvV0Ec)  and the screen do not scroll when I run the emulator

Comment: Can you post your new layout file?

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial for you how to use [ScrollView](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/)